# Remote ADB server: error: more than one device/emulator

Tags: android, automated-tests, appium, adb, remote-server

I perform remote mobile tests in the appium container.

On my computer I have an appium container based on the docker image appium/appium:v1.22.3-p1 with java 17 and maven 3.6.3.

I have an adb server running on a remote linux machine (on the local network), where smartphones are connected via USB. According to the [documentation][1].

When I have one smartphone connected to the remote server via USB and the test code is set to its UDID, everything works as it should.

```
UiAutomator2Options options = new UiAutomator2Options();
[...]
options.setRemoteAdbHost("10.38.223.243");
options.setAdbPort(5038);
options.setUdid(R58N12HEW3E);
```

However, if 3 smartphones are connected to the remote server and the test code is the same (aimed directly at one of the smartphone)

```
adb devices
List of devices attached
8e410c3e        device
R58N12HEW3E     device
RZCT50M61JX     device
```

I am getting an error.

```
Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: An unknown server-side error
occurred while processing the command. Original error: Error executing adbExec. Original
error: 'Command '/opt/android/platform-tools/adb -H 10.38.223.243 -P 5038 -s R58N12HEW3E
forward tcp\:8200 tcp\:6790' exited with code 1'; 
Command output: adb: error: more than one device/emulator
```

Evidently there is a problem with "adb forward" even though the **-s** flag is used.
I've been struggling with this problem for a few days now.
I am asking for advice.

Thanks!
[1]: https://github.com/appium/appium-docker-android#connect-to-an-adb-server